# how to run mysql_upgrade on windows

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have just upgraded (uninstall, restart, download new installer and installed) MySQL Server for Windows on my 2008 R2 box.

In the upgrade procedure webpage it says:

> To use mysql_upgrade, make sure that the server is running, and then
> invoke it like this:
>
> `shell> mysql_upgrade [options]`

But I can't figure that bit out...
I'm probably having a mental blank but if I run mysql_upgrade; through the mysql command line client, I get an error 1064: you have an error in your sql syntax etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `mysql_upgrade` command is system command, rather than a MySQL command.

Execute "`mysql_upgrade`" from the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`).  If it is not in your path, you can most likely find it at the following location:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

Or otherwise in the "bin" subdirectory of your MySQL server installation path.

You will likely want to pass it the root username and request it to prompt for your password as follows:

`mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Comment: That worked.  But I got a lot (I'm assuming all Wordpress database tables) of errors: "websitedatabasename.wp_posts doesn't exist"

Comment: Sounds possibly like InnoDB failed to start.  Can you pastebin your MySQL error log file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/h8EwCZrn

Comment: as a bit of background...   the old MySQL version (5.1) kept having issues starting, so I upgraded to the most recent windows release.
I've just copied all of the database folders for each website from the old \DATA\ folder into the new \DATA\ folder.  I haven't got any dumps or exports.

Comment: Wait!   I got it working.  I disabled the server, backed up the existing ibdata file, MySQL folder, ib_logfile(s) and replaced them with the files of the same name from the old 5.1 install.
Started the server and now all the websites are working again.

Comment: this time when I run `mysql_update -u root -p --force` all databases and tables return "OK".

Comment: When I run "mysql_upgrade -u root -p, it just says: "FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed".
Any ideas how I debug this?  Its just msql 5.6.  
The problem i have is that if I try to create a user, it instantly kills mysql with nothing in the logs.  I read that this can require an upgrade to fix, but upgrade fails.